# Coral edge TPU problems connecting and controlling a servo

Tags: servo, google-coral, edge-tpu

I’m having problems with coral board edge tpu interacting with a servo micro SG90. I don’t think that the problem is in the code because I tried it on the reaspberry pi and it worked, maybe the problem is the power voltage of the coral dev board.
Should I buy a separate battery pack to power the servo or is there another way?

[this is the circuit I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0M9k.png)

and this is the code:

import time

import board

import pulseio

from adafruit_motor import servo

pwm = pulseio.PWMOut(board.PWM3, duty_cycle=2 ** 15, frequency=50)

my_servo = servo.Servo(pwm)

while True:

```
for angle in range(0, 180, 5):  
    my_servo.angle = angle
    time.sleep(0.05)

for angle in range(180, 0, -5): 
    my_servo.angle = angle
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: What are the specs of the power adaptor that you are using ?

Comment: Switching Power Supply by LABITS

INPUT :100-240V.  50/60hz. 0,5A max
OUTPUT: 5.0V == 3.0A 15.0W

Answer (score 0):

The Coral-Dev-Board PWMs are per default configured as Open-Drain outputs, which means they toggle between "GND" and "Not Connected". Pi PWMs toggle between "GND" and "+3.3V".
Search for "Open-Drain" or "Open-Collector" and you will find examples on how to add some resistors/ transistors to you bread-board to be able to communicate with the servo.